# Insert an icon into a link with HTMLhelper in CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I want to replace text with a fontawesome icon in a link being created with CakePHP's HTMLhelper.

Here is the text version that works just fine:

```
Html->link('View', ['action' => 'view', $menuitem->id], ['title' => __('View'),'class' => 'btn btn-info btn-xs']) ?>
```

And here is an example of what I want to accomplish:

```
Html->link('span with icon goes here', ['action' => 'view', $menuitem->id], ['title' => __('View'),'class' => 'btn btn-info btn-xs']) ?>
```

Any ideas would be helpful. Thx!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `escape` option, ex:

```php
<?= $this->Html->link(
    '<span class="fa fa-search"></span><span class="sr-only">' . __('View') . '</span>',
    ['action' => 'view', $menuitem->id],
    ['escape' => false, 'title' => __('View'), 'class' => 'btn btn-info btn-xs']
) ?>
```

From [the docs](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/html.html#creating-links):

> HTML special characters in $title will be converted to HTML entities.
>   To disable this conversion, set the escape option to false in the
>   $options array.

```
echo $this->Html->link(
     $this->Html->image("recipes/6.jpg", ["alt" => "Brownies"]),
     "recipes/view/6",
     ['escape' => false] );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?= $this->Html->link('' ,['id' => 'logo',
'controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'], 
['class' => 'navbar-brand page-scroll']) ?>
```

I just set the image in the css and displayed like this